# Survey Monkey : Unknown error occurred while trying to Get Access Token

Tags: surveymonkey

I am trying to generate an access token and it is throwing an "Unknown error occured". This is really frustration when there is no specific error of what is the mistake i am doing in the procedure. The steps I followed are :

1. Register for a developer account and also survey monkey account
2. Create an application from which I got the api key
3. Trying to Get access token from the API Console

and this error comes up. I know the information is not that clear and please let me know if you need something. Please provide me with some pointers.

Thank you.

Comment: Errors like this are often caused by an incorrect client secret or client ID. Please double check that you have copied and pasted them correctly and without any leading or trailing spaces. If you're still having trouble, contact SurveyMonkey API support by emailing them at api-support@surveymonkey.com.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for the response. I am trying to create the access token under the Surveymonkey API Console which doesnt need any client Id. What could be the reason for this.

Comment: There may be a problem with the console's access token generation function. The developers are looking into it.

Comment: @TonyMayse... Thank you for the help. Will be waitin for a response

Comment: Just to close the loop on this - it was a temporary issue which has been resolved... Let us know if you continue to have any issues generating tokens.

Comment: I think I am able to generate the access token again. Thanks for the update.